# Wordpress shortcode to show categories

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm using Worpress to build a webshop and need some help with shortcodes. It's my first time using Wordpress. In my store categories I have made a category called "Brands", and inside of that I have placed another category named "Tarte" and inside the "Tarte" category I have placed my products. Now, how do I display all of the different brands that I place inside the "Brands" category? I have "Brands" set as the parent of "Tarte", and when I click my brands option in the meny I want to show all of the brands that the store carry.

With the shortcode **[product_categories parent="0"]** I display ALL the top categories, which are "Brands" and "Products".

And with the shortcode **[product_category category="Varumarken"]** ("Brands") I get ALL of the products inside my brands categories displayed.

I want to do something in the middle, to display the different brands. Can someone please help? If I'm inside my categories list and choose the "show" option when you hover over the edit options of the "Brands" category I get the page that I want: http://www.sannakarlin.com/wordpress/produkt-kategori/varumarken/ so I know it can be done. I really could use some help :)

Comment: You need to use [**`get_the_category()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Comment: Sorry, but how exactly do you mean? As I said I'm a newbe so you'll have to spell it out for me :) Thanks! :)

Comment: Search for `add_shortcode('product_categories'` in your theme or plugin files (the one that offers this shortcode to you), and adapt using the function I've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The **get_categories** function to retrieve categories name :-

```
<?php global $post, $product;
$categ = $product->get_categories();
echo $categ; ?>
```

You can use this code to display product categories name.